# Angular4 migrate from Http to HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-httpclient

I'm migrating my Angular app to use now the new HttpClient but I'm having some problems to achieve the same result I was getting with Http. Hope you guys can help me out.

So here's what I was doing with Http:

```
getAll() {
    return this.http.get(environment.API_DOMAIN + environment.CURRENCY_API_URL).map(res => {
        let response: ICurrenciesResponse = <ICurrenciesResponse> res.json();

        response.result = <Currency[]> res.json().result.map(service => {
            return new Currency(<ICurrency> service);
        });

    return response;
    });
}
```

The response is typed with the interface ICurrenciesResponse witch looks like this:

```
import { IGenericResponse } from '../igeneric-response';
import { Currency } from '../../classes/currency';
export interface ICurrenciesResponse extends IGenericResponse {
    result?: Currency[]
}
```

As you can see the interface extends IGenericResponse and is composed by an array of Currency witch is a defined class. In order to have this array properly setted I had to do the secound map where then I create a new Currency object. This works perfectly and I'm very happy with the method so far.

Know, when I migrate to HttpClient I have this:

```
getAll(): Promise<ICurrenciesResponse> {
    return this.http
        .get<ICurrenciesResponse>(environment.API_DOMAIN + environment.CURRENCY_API_URL)
        .toPromise();
}
```

But know my Currency array is not properly setted as an array of Currency's. Wasn't HttpClient suppose to cast the data according to the interface defined as a type on the get method? 
If not, what's the best way to achieve the same I did with Http? Use subscribe() in stead of toPromisse() and process the data the same way I'm already doing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should remove the angularjs tag - this question is only about Angular 4.x and not 1.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `HttpClient` tries to find the right content-type for the response, it's not creating instances for you from data inside the response.

You still have to use the `map` operator and create the instances inside it. But you have to remove the `.json()` call.

```
getAll() {
    let url = environment.API_DOMAIN + environment.CURRENCY_API_URL;
    return this.http
        .get<ICurrenciesResponse>(url)
        .map(response => {
            if(Array.isArray(response.result) {
              response.result = response.result.map(service => new Currency(service));
            }
            return response;
        });
}
```